# How to retrieve only unique values from arraylist<hashmap<>> from Sqlite database into listview in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, hashmap

I am inserting data into SQLite database using ArrayList>. I want to retrieve only unique values into a listview using simple adapter. I am using the same key to insert the values. how can i get only different values into the listview?
Here's my code..

Databasehandler.java

```
public void insertAnimal(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("animalName", queryValues.get("animalName"));
    database.insert("animals", null, values);
    database.close();
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllAnimals() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM animals";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();              
            map.put("animalId", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("animalName", cursor.getString(1));
                wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }

    return wordList;
}
```

And here's my MainActivity.java

```
DBController controller = new DBController(this);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> animalList =                          controller.getAllAnimals();
if(animalList.size()!=0) {
ListView lv = getListView();
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,animalList,  R.layout.view_animal_entry, new String[] { "animalId","animalName"}, new int[]        {R.id.animalId, R.id.animalName}); 
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the DISTINCT keyword to eliminate duplicate rows from a results set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM animals
```

Note that this will only remove rows that are duplicate in terms of all columns. So if you have the same animal name under different ids, you'll still get both rows. For example if your table contains:

```
animalId   animalName
1          Lion
1          Lion
2          Lion
3          Tiger
3          Tiger
```

The results would be:

```
animalId   animalName
1          Lion
2          Lion
3          Tiger
```

An alternative would be to group by the animal name:

```
SELECT * FROM animals
GROUP BY animalName
```

The result would (most likely) be:

```
animalId   animalName
2          Lion
3          Tiger
```

Note that here, you now have unique names. However in the case of a name that was grouped (Lion in this example) the animalId you get for it will be from one of the rows from the set that was grouped. The exact one you get is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the records with different animalIDs then you would do something like this

```
public Cursor getUniqueValues() {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            allColumns, SQLiteHelper.ANIMAL_ID + " like \'Whatever\'", null, null, null, null ,null);

    return cursor;
}
```